# Need clarification of variables in mule

Tags: mule

I have few questions regarding variables in mule.

1. If I have a payload like below,

What is the best way to access this information inside Groovy script? #[payload] doesn't seem to work...

```
<scripting:script engine="Groovy">
...
qr.update(conn, "INSERT INTO event values(#[payload], 1)");
..
</scripting:script>
```

1. How to store a value coming out from a particular point in a flow to a variable that I can use it at any later point of time.
2. If I have a payload of type string and if I need to parse the string (to get various data) using a custom java class. How to get the values back from java class.

For Example I have a string as below,

```
SNO           :1
Application   : a
```

I have a java class that parses the string and returns the value using get set methods.

CustomString.class is just a bean.

getSno will return serial number.
getApplication will return application name

I am not sure how to pass the value from mule to java class and get back the value to mule.

Do I need to use,

```
public Object transform(MuleMessage message, String encoding) throws TransformerException
```

If the initial payload below has the above string, can I just pass this payload to custom transformer and get the desired value back from the transformer?

```
<set-payload value="values #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload" />
<transformer ref="customTransformer" doc:name="Transform string"/>
<set-payload value="values #[payload['sNo']]" doc:name="Set Payload" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Groovy, the `payload` variable is bound to the message payload. You can use it directly. `#[payload]` is a MEL expression and has nothing to do with Groovy.
2. It depends what you do mean by "any point of time". If it's in the same flow or a flow referenced by it, you can use `set-variable`. If it's in another flow after an endpoint interaction (outbound -> inbound), use `set-property` and you'll find the value in the inbound scope in the next flow. Alternatively, you can use `set-session-variable` to store the value in the Mule session, which will be maintained across flows.
3. Either create a transformer, as you're showing above, or just use a plain POJO as a `component` with a single method that takes a String and return the Bean. The latter approach has the advantage it doesn't tie you to the Mule API.